# fetch html code, edit it and load it with web view

Tags: html, uiwebview, load, edit, fetch

am new to the iphone development and I have a problem to display a certain site that is essential for my app. 
What I want to do is to display this site with no horizontal scrolling and with a text size that can be read without zooming in or out.
As far as I understand this is impossible without mess with the html source code.
But I have no idea how to fetch it, and most importantly how to modify it and with which tools I can do that.
And then how I can load that code in my web view.
I know that I ask to much but I want to learn how to do this stuff and I don't search for someone to give me a ready solution but to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to render a site which is not under your control and add certain style changes (font size, no-scroll, etc) to it.

If what you need from the page doesn't change (i.e. it's a static page), then this should be fairly easy.  You simply copy the code from the source by saving the page as an HTML file from your web browser.  From there, you can use your favorite HTML/CSS editor to make the changes that you need and then host it yourself.

If you don't want to host the code yourself and/or the page is dynamic then you're going to need to give us more information to adequately answer this question.

Comment: Thank for answering. Thats exactly what I want. I want to render a site which is not under your control and add certain style changes (font size, no-scroll, etc) to it. But the page is dynamic. So what are the choices that I have?

Comment: What are you going to have to do is write a style sheet that overrides the native style of the page you wish to modify.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If you can give me some links to study them or more information on how I can do this.